# SQLite3 Group By incorrectly returning only 1 row

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, group-by

I have an issue with sqlite3 within node.js

I have the table with about 5000 rows and 3 columns: itemId, provider, price

I am trying to group on itemId and get the avg(price) where provider = "X".

The code is as follows:

```
var sql = "SELECT itemId, avg(price) from dataset where provider = ? group by ?";

db.each(sql, ["clerk", "itemId"],
    function (err, row) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(row)
    },
    function (err, cntx) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Number of retrieved rows is ' + cntx);
    }); 
};
```

The issue is that this statement is only returning 1 row with the 1st itemId in the where clause but the average is of the whole where clause. There should be 8 rows returned. When I do:

```
select distinct(itemId) from dataset where provider = ?
```

it returns 8 rows.

I've tried using distinct on itemId as well as making itemId both an INTEGER and TEXT field. Neither worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?`s are used to bind **values**. When you use it like that, you're in fact grouping by the **string `'itemId'`**, and not by the `itemId` column. Since it's a constant, all the rows have the same value, and you get one row as a result.

Since you have `itemId` in the select list, you can't really change this value - using any other column would just cause the SQL query to fail, so you could just write it in there explicitly:

```
var sql = "SELECT itemId, avg(price) from dataset where provider = ? group by itemId";
```

Comment: Wow... I have been at work too long. That you for catching my slip up. Works!